# Parse ElasticSearch output with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'd like to parse the `_source` field of an ElasticSearch output. Here's an example of mine (it only contains one list of values):

```
"_source":
{    
   "key1": "value1",    
   "key2": "value2"
},
{    
   "key1": "value1",    
   "key2": "value2"
},
etc.
```

I know how to get to `_source` but I don't know how to parse it. It seems to be a single node, isn't it?

EDIT:

I tried to 'reach' the `_source` field but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
final ArrayNode _source = (ArrayNode) jsonNode.path(ES_HITS).path(ES_HITS).path(ES_SOURCE);
for (JsonNode value : _source)
{
        try 
        {
            lov.add(mapper.treeToValue(value, Lov.class));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {   logger.error("GetLibelles : add : error : JsonProcessingException", e); }
        }
```

**Lov class**

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Lov extends ParentModel implements Serializable
{   
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    private String key3;
    private String key4;

    // getters and setters
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.MissingNode incompatible with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode
```

The ElasticSearch output:

```
{
 "took":0,
 "timed_out":false,
 "_shards":
 {
    "total":1,
    "successful":1,
    "failed":0
 },
"hits":
{ 
   "total":1,
   "max_score":1.0,
   "hits":
    [
       {
          "_index":"bla",
          "_type":"lov",
          "_id":"PWA8bmEBRDuys8JUCwg10w",
          "_score":1.0,
          "_source":
          {    
              "key1": "value1",    
              "key2": "value2"
          },
          {    
              "key1": "value1",    
              "key2": "value2"
          }
       } 
    ]
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The mapping was good but the insertion was not. To correctly insert multiple documents, I had to use the [Bulk API](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bulk.html).

Once the mapping is done, I have to insert my data using the following command:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'serverAddress/_bulk' --data-binary @data.json; echo
```

**data.json**

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "yourIndex", "_type" : "lov"}}
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "yourIndex", "_type" : "lov"}}
{ "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

> In the same way that mget allows us to retrieve multiple documents at once, the bulk API allows us to make multiple create, index, update, or delete requests in a single step.

I need to insert my data, therefore I choose the `index` action. **Each request needs an action**.

Do no forget:

> 1. Every line must end with a newline character (\n), including the last line. These are used as markers to allow for efficient line separation.
> 2. The lines cannot contain unescaped newline characters, as they would interfere with parsing. This means that the JSON must not be pretty-printed.

Comment: would you care to elaborate your answer please!

Answer (score 0):

If your query returns multiple hits, then "_source" property will be present in each of the returned hits. (see here in the [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) )

To parse the json with jackson, just make a POJO that matches the json schema. In your case, this should be class (Result.java) that contains the both properties key1 and key2. Then map the json string to your pojo class with the jackson ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Result result = mapper.readValue("{\"key1\":\"value1\",..}",result.class);
```

Behind the "_source" property should normally be only one object, I suppose. Is the code you provided from the real use case, or just an example?

Comment: The query will always return the same value, which is presented above in the OP. I have trouble to parse this value, which is represented as a list of values (as you can see there are several brackets, but it's the same value). I hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: Can you include the source code of Lov.class and what error message do you get? Actually, this is not a list of values, which is very strange. A list of json values would look like [{},{},..]. Is the answer automatically generated or manually?

Comment: I've updated my loop. See OP with new code and error line. The answer is manually inserted in the `lov` index of the ElasticSearch engine. Should I have insert the list of values differently? Thanks for you help.

Comment: It looks to me, that the "_source" field you are getting is not a valid json. This means, it is not an array of json objects, as it should be.

Comment: Practically, you have "_source": {"key1":"value1"..}, {"key1":"value1"..} . And what you should get from elasticsearch is "_source": [{"key1":"value1"..}, {"key1":"value1"..}] -> an array of json objects.

Comment: You seem to be right. However I don't know how to insert a an array of values as a single value without getting a parse error. I'm using the curl commande given here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/docs-index_.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74624/discussion-between-q3sand-and-zlobi-wan-kenobi).